# Mayavi and Texture Mapping (or turning a 2D image into a 3D image)

Tags: python, texture-mapping, mayavi, uv-mapping

I have a project where I have a 2D image but I need to then turn this into a 3D object.  I already have the skeleton model of the object, it is a simple matter of applying color to the surface.  I have been looking around and it seems 3D programs like Blender have a method like this called texture mapping or uv mapping.  However I was assigned to use Mayavi and Python, and so far I could not really find anything about texture mapping in the Mayavi documentation.  I was wondering if someone knows how (if possible) to perform texture mapping in Mayavi.

Alternatively, if texture mapping is not possible, what would be the best way (if there is a way) to turn a 2D image into a 3D object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is documentation on Mayavi with examples on texture mapping: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#texture-mapping-actors.
If this is not what you need you can always script with Blender like you previously mentioned.
http://www.blender.org/education-help/python/

Comment: I guess my next question would be, if I use blender would I be able to create a stand alone application.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not knowledgeable to provide you with an answer, and I don't have the time to research the answer because I must catch my flight soon. A link that might help you : http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/#standalone-modules